# how to sort the json array by keys in descending order using angular

Tags: arrays, json, angular

```
var arr = {
      '2021-07-20-21:10': {
        sends: 1,
        recvs: 1,
        notSents: 0,
        rejects: 0,
        xptSkips: 0,
        timeouts: 0,
        appErrors: 0,
        responseTimeAvg: 172,
        responseTimeMax: 172,
        when: '21:10',
        hostCount: 1,
      },
      '2021-07-20-21:22': {
        sends: 1,
        recvs: 0,
        notSents: 0,
        rejects: 0,
        xptSkips: 0,
        timeouts: 1,
        appErrors: 0,
        responseTimeAvg: 0,
        responseTimeMax: 0,
        when: '21:22',
        hostCount: 1,
      },
      '2021-07-20-21:13': {
        sends: 2,
        recvs: 1,
        notSents: 0,
        rejects: 0,
        xptSkips: 0,
        timeouts: 1,
        appErrors: 0,
        responseTimeAvg: 89,
        responseTimeMax: 177,
        when: '21:13',
        hostCount: 2,
      },
      '2021-07-20-21:14': {
        sends: 1,
        recvs: 0,
        notSents: 0,
        rejects: 0,
        xptSkips: 0,
        timeouts: 1,
        appErrors: 0,
        responseTimeAvg: 0,
        responseTimeMax: 0,
        when: '21:14',
        hostCount: 1,
      }}
```

and it has to be sorted based on keys in desc order

```
var arr = {
      '2021-07-20-21:22': {
        sends: 1,
        recvs: 1,
        notSents: 0,
        rejects: 0,
        xptSkips: 0,
        timeouts: 0,
        appErrors: 0,
        responseTimeAvg: 172,
        responseTimeMax: 172,
        when: '21:22',
        hostCount: 1,
      },
      '2021-07-20-21:14': {
        sends: 1,
        recvs: 0,
        notSents: 0,
        rejects: 0,
        xptSkips: 0,
        timeouts: 1,
        appErrors: 0,
        responseTimeAvg: 0,
        responseTimeMax: 0,
        when: '21:14',
        hostCount: 1,
      },
      '2021-07-20-21:13': {
        sends: 2,
        recvs: 1,
        notSents: 0,
        rejects: 0,
        xptSkips: 0,
        timeouts: 1,
        appErrors: 0,
        responseTimeAvg: 89,
        responseTimeMax: 177,
        when: '21:13',
        hostCount: 2,
      },
      '2021-07-20-21:10': {
        sends: 1,
        recvs: 0,
        notSents: 0,
        rejects: 0,
        xptSkips: 0,
        timeouts: 1,
        appErrors: 0,
        responseTimeAvg: 0,
        responseTimeMax: 0,
        when: '21:10',
        hostCount: 1,
      }}
```

Comment: Please use syntax highlight for your code and indent it.

Comment: You must use the function [sort](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort) to sort your array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can extract the "keys" of your array using the Object.keys() function, then use the sort function to sort that array of keys, and generate a new object iterating over each keys there... Code would be (keeping *arr* as the name of your array):

```
// Get the keys of your "array"
let arrayOfKeys = Object.keys(arr)

// We sort it out...
let sortedArray = arrayOfKeys.sort()

// We will create the "final" array
let resultingArray = {}

// Now we iterate over each element, in order:
sortedArray.forEach((element) => {
    resultingArray[element] = arr[element]
})
```

...of course this can be shortened wildly, for example:

```
var resultingArr = {}
Object.keys(arr).sort().forEach(e -> { resultingArr[e] = arr[e] })
```

EDIT: I see that you need to sort the array in *descending* order. This can be done using a custom sort function, or using the function reverse(). Just correct the sorting step:

```
// We sort it out...
let sortedArray = arrayOfKeys.sort().reverse()
```